# Julia - how to nicely format arrays in linux terminal

Tags: arrays, terminal, formatting, julia

Using Julia 0.5.0, I'm writing a script which I execute from a system terminal, **NOT** the REPL. In the output, arrays are printed without any formatting, making the results difficult to read.

```
#!/usr/bin/julia

A = [1 2; 3 4]
print(A)
```

---

```
$ chmod +x ex_julia.jl
$ ./ex_julia.jl 

[1 2; 3 4]
```

The best way I've found to nicely print arrays is to use `display(myArray)`, but this prints metadata as well as array contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/julia

A = [1 2; 3 4]
display(A)
```

---

```
$ ./ex_julia.jl 

2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

How can I print the *contents* of a julia array, nicely formatted, in a shell terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `display` function seems to make use internally of the `print_matrix` command, which can be imported from `Base`. (defined in `show.jl`)

```
julia> import Base.print_matrix
julia> A = [1 2 ; 3 4];
julia> print_matrix(STDOUT, A);
 1  2
 3  4
```

Otherwise you could also try the `Base.showarray` function which may be more useful to you; the optional keyword "header=false" removes the header that you're trying to get rid of:

```
julia> Base.showarray(STDOUT, A, false; header=false);
```

Comment: Since v1.0, `STDOUT` has been re-named to the lowercase `stdout` (see [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/25959))